# Is it possible to test Portlet Controllers using Springs MockMvc?

Tags: testing, spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc, spring-mvc-test

You can test your "normal" Spring MVC Controllers using the MockMvc class like so:

```
    mockMvc
        .perform(get("/my/fine/path"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

From the [Spring Reference on Handler Mappings](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html#portlet-handlermapping):

> Since there is really no such thing as a URL within a Portlet, we must use other mechanisms to control mappings. The two most common are the portlet mode and a request parameter, but anything available to the portlet request can be used in a custom handler mapping.

Is MockMvc only for "normal" Controllers or is there a way of using it when testing Portlet Controllers?

Comment: I will be interested to see if you get any answers to this. In the meantime you may find this of interest regarding portlet controller testing: http://jamesfarrell129.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/integration-testing-for-spring-portlet-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout spring-test-portlet-mvc (https://github.com/markusf/spring-test-portlet-mvc), which exposes the features of MockMvc to the Portal context!